# Project Euler 18

Tags: c#

Hey, been working at Project Euler, and this one is giving me some problems

> By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom is 23.
>
> 3
>
> 7 4
>
> 2 4 6
>
> 8 5 9 3
>
> That is, 3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23.
>
> Find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle below:
>
> ...
>
> NOTE: As there are only 16384 routes, it is possible to solve this problem by trying every route. However, Problem 67, is the same challenge with a triangle containing one-hundred rows; it cannot be solved by brute force, and requires a clever method! ;o)

here's the algorithm I've used to solve it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Problem18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string triangle = @"75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23";
            string[] rows = triangle.Split('\n');
            int currindex = 1;
            int total = int.Parse(rows[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(rows[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] array1 = rows[i].Split(' ');
                if (array1.Length > 1)
                {
                    if (int.Parse(array1[currindex - 1]) > int.Parse(array1[currindex]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(array1[currindex - 1]);
                        total += int.Parse(array1[currindex - 1]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(array1[currindex]);
                        total += int.Parse(array1[currindex]);
                        currindex++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total: " + total);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

now whenever i run it, it comes up with 1064, only 10 less then the solution -- 1074

i haven't found any problems with the algorithm and I did the problem by hand and also came up with 1064, anyone know if the solution is wrong, i'm interpreting the question wrong, or if there's just a flaw in the algorithm?

Comment: `75+64+82+87+82+75+73+28+83+32+91+78+58+73+93 = 1074`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that your algorithm is a greedy algorithm, always finding local maxima. Unfortunately that causes it to miss higher numbers down below because they are directly below lower numbers. For example, if the triangle were only 3 levels, your algorithm would pick 75 + 95 + 47 = 217, while the correct answer is 75 + 64 + 82 = 221.

The correct algorithm will either try every path and choose the one with the highest total, or compute paths from the bottom up (which allows you to avoid trying every one, thus being much faster). I should add that working from the bottom-up is not only much faster (O(n^2) instead of O(2^n)!), but also much easier to write (I did it in about 3 lines of code).

Comment: Are you sure working from the bottom up is correct, and leads to the correct result? It wouldn't work for a greedy algorithm - https://gist.github.com/791893 (actually, I'm not sure that's what you meant. I'm probably misunderstanding `:P`)

Comment: Kobi: Yes, bottom-up is correct (or at least it gets me 1074). You are right that a greedy algorithm will not work.

Comment: Going bottom up would really only help if you implement it as a caching algorithm or am I missing something? This could be done quite effectively though, as you only need to keep the information about two rows at any point.  EDIT: I'm talking about efficency now

Comment: I know this is old, but I was working on this problem today. The instructions clearly say "Find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle below". I see how working from the bottom can give a different result, but that's not what the problem says.

Comment: Doug: The reason why this still works is it is finding the best top to bottom path, it's just not finding the path by going from the top to bottom. 

Also I chose this answer as correct because it is the best answer that explains why the algorithm I used didn't work, and also details on a correct algorithm along with [faster] more accurate algorithms than the one I used

Comment: @Gabe, what are adjacent numbers? and under which subject in math this kind of problems are being addressed? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a graphical description:

[image]

Comment: only one number is added to each row, not two

Comment: after "then replace the max sum in the rhird row, deleting the last" there is an error in the first item of the last row: mustn't it be 9 instead of 16??

Answer (score 12):

Here's what the bottom up method belisarius describes--using the trivial triangle given in problem 18--looks like, just in case the image in his post is confusing to anyone else.

```
      03
    07  04
  02  04  06
08  05  09  03

      03
    07  04
  02  04  06
08  05  09  03
^^^^^^

      03
    07  04
  10  04  06
08  05  09  03
    ^^^^^^

      03
    07  04
  10  13  06
08  05  09  03
        ^^^^^^

      03
    07  04
  10  13  15
  ^^^^^^
08  05  09  03

      03
    20  04
  10  13  15
      ^^^^^^
08  05  09  03

      03
    20  04
  10  13  15
      ^^^^^^
08  05  09  03

      03
    20  19
    ^^^^^^
  10  13  15
08  05  09  03

      23
      ^^
    20  19
  10  13  15
08  05  09  03
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize now that my algorithm solves a slightly different triangle. Yours is more accurate

Comment: @belisarius However, your algorithm put me on the right track to find this answer, so thank _you_ as well.

Answer (score 6):

You've written a [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm), which I don't think fits the requirements here. Here's a quick example to demonstrate that point:

```
  1
 2 1
1 1 100
```

Using your algorithm you'll reach a sum of 4, although the optimal solution is 102.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good question based on **dynamic programming**. You need to create a 2d data structure(like vector in c++) then follow the bottom to up approach of dp.

The formula is ***dp[i][j] += max(dp[i + 1][j], dp[i + 1][j + 1])***. Try coding on your own then if you are stuck at some point see my solution.

```
vector< vector<int> > dp(n); // n is the number of rows
for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        cin >> val;
        dp[i].push_back(val);
    }
}
for (int i = n - 2 ; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        dp[i][j] += max(dp[i + 1][j], dp[i + 1][j + 1]);    
}
cout << dp[0][0] << endl;   
return 0;
}
```

input: 3
2
4 5
6 8 9

output: 16

Answer (score -1):

Recursive (not necessarily the best) approach:

```
    static int q18(){
        int matrix[][] = // BIG MATRIX;
        return getMaxPath(matrix, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    static int getMaxPath(int matrix[][], int sum, int row, int col){
        if(row==matrix.length) return sum;
        return Math.max(getMaxPath(matrix, sum+matrix[row][col], row+1, col),
                        getMaxPath(matrix, sum+matrix[row][col], row+1, col+1));
    }
```

Comment: The reason is because it doesn't answer the question.  The question wasn't asking about ways to solve problem 18, it was asking about why the algorithm I used didn't work.  In all the other answers, they explained the issue with the algorithm and potential ways to solve it (namely not using a greedy algorithm). It also does not add to the answers that were already given. I hope this clears things up, there's a page on answering questions in the help center for more information.